# Is "get something straight for" an idiom?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

> He really needed to **get his accent straight for**, although in Europe he was considered something of a prodigy in Persian, South Asians found Jones impossible to understand when he spoke to them in that language, taking it to be English. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKvtCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=He%20really%20needed%20to%20get%20his%20accent%20straight%20for,%20although%20in%20Europe%20he%20was%20considered%20something%20of%20a%20prodigy%20in%20Persian,%20South%20Asians%20found%20Jones%20impossible%20to%20understand%20when%20he%20spoke%20to%20them%20in%20that%20language,%20taking%20it%20to%20be%20English.&source=bl&ots=zpTULNRYhE&sig=SqyDunUYLr5M-7jhWUKWiqFF_d4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLiqjctqDdAhWE11MKHXSJDwYQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=He%20really%20needed%20to%20get%20his%20accent%20straight%20for%2C%20although%20in%20Europe%20he%20was%20considered%20something%20of%20a%20prodigy%20in%20Persian%2C%20South%20Asians%20found%20Jones%20impossible%20to%20understand%20when%20he%20spoke%20to%20them%20in%20that%20language%2C%20taking%20it%20to%20be%20English.&f=false))

Is the phrase "get something straight for" idiomatic? I have heard, very often, "get something straight". What does "get something straight for" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For" is being used to mean "because".

Simplified:

> He really needed to get his accent straight, for South Asians found Jones impossible to understand.

Comment: Is "taking it to be ..." in "taking it to be English" also a set phrase?

Comment: @dan https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take sense 12.

Comment: @userr2684291, It seems that the implication is that Jones' English is really bad and South Asians are even not sure if he spoke to them in English. Have I gotten it right?

Comment: @dan No: *take X to be Y* means, as per the Longman dictionary entry, "consider X to be Y". Does that help?

Comment: @userr2684291, I meant the implication of the whole sentence, not just that phrase. I got the meaning for the phrase though.

Comment: @dan I know what you meant. Read the sentence carefully: why would he consider it a problem if South Asians took the language in which he spoke to them to be English? In what language did he speak to them?

Comment: @userr2684291: I get a bit lost here after a careful read! lol. It seems to me that  South Asians found Jones impossible to understand when he spoke Persian, but now I don't know what 'taking it to English' is doing there.

Comment: @dan What would make you think someone is speaking English if they were in fact speaking Persian or some other language? Why do you think **Jones** had to get his accent straight?

Comment: @userr2684291, well, the best I can get is that Jones spoke Persian (which is not understandable to South Asians) and they took what he spoke is English though he spoke Persian. Maybe, that's why he need to get his accent straight?

Comment: @dan Jones spoke English, and was most likely British. His English accent was too strong, rendering his Persian unintelligible to such an extent that people thought he spoke English.

Comment: @userr2684291, you are saying: "Jones taking Persian to be English"? I thought "South Asians taking Jones' Persian to be English", which made me misunderstand I think.

Comment: @dan I haven't said that. Jones spoke Persian in addition to English. However, he spoke with a heavy English accent whenever he'd speak Persian.

Comment: @dan To add to what userr2684291 has explained, Jones was a colonial era European scholar traveling to and living in South Asia. It was a time when Persian was widely spoken and understood in the Indian subcontinent. The line I quoted is saying Jones spoke Persian with a thick English accent so most local people didn't understand him and thought he was speaking English to them.